# Why does ServiceStack not add the CORS headers when the HTTP status code is 204 No Content?

Tags: servicestack, cors

Why does **ServiceStack** not add the **CORS** headers when the HTTP status code is **204** No Content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested this with the latest version of ServiceStack:

Configure ServiceStack to return **204 NoContent** for `null` or `void` responses:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    Return204NoContentForEmptyResponse = true,
});
```

Add Custom CORS configuration:

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
    allowCredentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Allow, Authorization"));
```

Add new Services returning `void` and `null` responses:

```
[Route("/void-response")]
public class TestVoidResponse { }

[Route("/null-response")]
public class TestNullResponse { }

public class TestServices : Service
{
    public void Any(TestVoidResponse response) {}

    public object Any(TestNullResponse response)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Call the above Services:

- http://test.servicestack.net/void-response
- http://test.servicestack.net/null-response

Both Services return **204 NoContent** with CORS Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.00 Win32NT/.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Allow, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 19 Feb 2015 15:10:50 GMT
```